# Import existing Laravel 5 project

Tags: php, import, laravel-5

I had my working laravel 5 project. After I reset my laptop, I had to install all softwares including Laravel.

After that, I have **copy & pasted the project** what I kept in my backups to continue to work. 
I have executed the below commands:

`composer update`

`composer install`

But I get the following error in browser when I try to access the URLs.

(E.g: http://localhost/IntelliKid/public/)

**`Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`**

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 802
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Also share your route for which this error is coming ?

Comment: Does http://localhost/IntelliKid/ or http://localhost/ work?

Comment: When I type 'localhost/' it displays a XAMPP Dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Open up the cmd prompt.
2. Change the directory into your laravel folder (E.g IntelliKid).
3. Type "php artisan serve" and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

   Note: it will say "Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000".
4. Then you are able to run this url "http:// localhost:8000" instead "http:// localhost/IntelliKid/public/"

Now the page you are looking for could be found.

Cheers :)